# Is there any other class that qualifies for the "prepared" side of Ultimate Magus than the Wizard?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, class

[Ultimate magus](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20061010a&page=3) allows you to advance both a *"prepared"* and a *"spontaneous"* arcane class spellcasting progression.

The most obvious choice would be Sor/Wiz, but Bard/Wiz works too.

There are several other choices on the spontaneous side.

But so far, only Wizard for the prepared side.

So is there any other class that fulfills the prepared requirement?

> able to prepare and cast 2nd-level arcane spells from a spellbook.

Answer (score 3):

Perusing the [3.5 Caster Classes Index](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=8768.0), I filtered on "prepared arcane" and then looked them up to further filter by usage of spellbook.

It appears that the most viable alternative to a *Wizard* would be the *Wu Jen*, from *Complete Arcane*.

---

The full list of classes preparing arcane spells from spellbooks.

Classes:

- **Death Master** (*Dragon Compendium*, p. 30); own spell list,
- **Wizard** (*Player's Handbook*); own spell list,
- **Wu Jen** (*Complete Arcane*, p. 14); own spell list.

Prestige Classes:

- **Bladesinger** (*Races of Faerûn*, p. 179); own spell list, tops at 4th level,
- **Merchant Prince** ([*Power of Faerûn*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060308a&page=4)); own spell list, tops at 3rd level,
- **Prime Underdark Guide** (*Underdark*, p. 40); own spell list, tops at 4th level.

Comment: In addition to native prepared arcane casting, any character with prepared casting can be a prepared arcane caster, with the right feats.  So Cleric/Cleric and Druid/Druid are valid choices, for example (since both are both prepared and spontaneous casters). Preparing from a spellbook is harder, but the spellbook class and the advanced class need not be the same.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: I was actually surprised as how few classes seemed to be dependent on a spellbook. Given the number of caster classes, I had expected quite a lot more! I was also wondering if spells obtained through "Sword of the Arcane Order" would count as Arcane spellcasting (it is prepared and based off a spellbook).